# Push changes to TortoiseHG's web server fails with "Aborted Push"

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm not using authentication with TortoiseHG but simply needed to see if a colleague could push some changes to me. He can browse my repo from the url that the web server provides and can pull changesets from me fine.

What he can't do is push them to me over the built-in web server. I have configured it in TortoiseHG to have "*" next to "Allow Push" in settings which should let anyone push without authentication.

Still, when TortoiseHG tries to push, I just get "Aborted Push" in the status bar.

Does anyone know a way to get more information on why it would abort?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, pushes are only accepted over SSL. You need to set web.push_ssl to false:

```
   push_ssl

          Whether  to  require that inbound pushes be transported over SSL
          to prevent password sniffing. Default is True.
```